# What was the name of the planet which was referred to as "House" in the "The Doctors Wife"? (SE06EP04)

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

Hands down one of my favorite episodes, if not THE favorite of all time, I am trying to figure out what the name of the planet 'House' was from. I name all of my devices after Whovian planetary guidance, but for the life of me, cannot find any reference to a planet here. Any thoughts? Or was there a name for the bubble universe it belonged to?

Answer (score 5):

The Doctor identifies the House as an asteroid within its own pocket universe. Since the entire thing is one entity (with an asteroid-looking shell wrapped around it), presumably its name is "The House" rather than the planet(oid) having a separate name.

> **DOCTOR:** *I see. This **asteroid** is sentient.*
>
> ...
>
> **DOCTOR:** *Yes. So you're like a sea urchin. Hard outer surface, that's the planet we're walking on. Big, squashy, oogly thing inside, that's you.*
>
> **HOUSE** [OC]: *That is correct, Time Lord.*

The House asteroid exists *outside the universe*. Rory tried to get a handle on whether it's in a separate *bubble* universe but the Doctor shoots him down. No name is given for the place.

> **DOCTOR:** *Imagine a great big soap bubble with one of those tiny little bubbles on the outside.*
>
> **RORY:** *Okay.*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *Well, it's nothing like that.*